# No matches with c++11 regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Why does this find no matches in g++ (Debian 4.6.3-1) 4.6.3 or clang version 3.2 (trunk 159457)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line("test");
    regex pattern("test",regex_constants::grep);
    smatch result;

    bool ret(false);
    ret = regex_search(line,result,pattern);  
    cout <<  boolalpha << ret << endl;
    cout <<  result.size() << endl;
    return 0 ;
}
```

output

```
false
0
```

Answer (score 15):

Because `<regex>` is not yet implemented in libstdc++, as documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) (§28).

For now, use [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) or [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

By now your example runs correctly:

```
$ ~/src/gcc/inst/bin/g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.9.0 20140224 (experimental)
```

on

```
$ uname -a
Linux ... x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

executes

```
$ ./83-regex.x 
true
1
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this change log `<regex>` is supported in **gcc-4.9** with libstd++-v3

http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html