# C++11 Regex Grouping

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No matches with c++11 regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269766/no-matches-with-c11-regex)

I was reading this book that covers C++11 and I got to the chapter that talks about  Regular Expressions. Everything was working fine for me until I got the part about grouping and referring to \1 whenever I needed to refer back to a group. My code compiles perfectly fine :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
int main()
{
     try
     {


           regex r1("<(.*)>.*</\\1>");
           bool found = regex_match(string("<tag>value</tag>"),r1);
           cout << "Does the string match:        ";
           cout << boolalpha << found << '\n';
     }catch( exception e)
     {
        cout << e.what() << '\n';
     }

     return 0;
}
```

What happens however is I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) message. This little snippet was used directly from the book so I highly doubt this is wrong.
Note:  I do compile using -std=c++0x.
Note:  I'm using Code::Blocks under Ubuntu 12.04

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libstdc++'s implementation of regex is HILARIOUSLY incomplete.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Head down to section 28, regular expressions. If you're using libstdc++ (which is almost certain as you're on ubuntu) then you cannot use regex yet.

It's a shame, because g++'s toolchain for C++11 is otherwise extremely solid.

You'll need to use boost for this probably, or another regex library.  Or change over the clang (and clang's libraries) or to MSVC (and their libraries).

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work under g++ / libstdc++.  Because it's not yet implemented.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your comment. Do you know any other compiler that has it fully implemented?

Comment: Clang and MSVC, if I recall correctly. ;)

Comment: @user1274223: Obviously not enough to accept the answer...