# What is my mistake in this regular expression using std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm using gcc 4.6.3 with -std=c++0x

It's the first time I use std::regex. And I can't see my mistake:

- The input parsed std::string starts with `GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1` while my regex pattern is `GET(.*)`.
- The result group 1 is evaluated to `T /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1`
  whereas I expected something more like `/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1`

I don't understand why does it keep the `T` ?

Here's my code:

```
static const std::string strRegExp="GET(.*)";
std::string computeRequestedItem(const std::string& strHttpRequest)
{
    std::cout << "SEARCHING :" << strRegExp << "in :" << strHttpRequest;
    std::string strResult;
    std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> result;
    static const std::regex pattern(strRegExp); 
    bool bValid = std::regex_match(strHttpRequest, result, pattern);

    if(!bValid)
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        return strResult;   
    }

    strResult = result[1];

std::cout << "Requested item: " << strResult << std::endl;

    return strResult;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
SEARCHING :GET(.*)in :GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.04 Chromium/20.0.1132.47 Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ 
Requested item: T /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.04 Chromium/20.0.1132.47 Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Comment: Add a "debug line" before `regex_match` to print your `strRegExp` and `pattern`. What does it print?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No matches with c++11 regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269766/no-matches-with-c11-regex)

Comment: Your mistake is using gcc regex. Charitably, it doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libstdc++ regex support is only partial. Please [see here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) and read `28 Regular Expression`. I believe the code you have should work fine. As a test, I changed `std` to `boost` and compiled your code with boost::regex and got the following results as you expected:

> Requested item:  /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1

I would suggest using `boost::regex` until libstdc++ regex is fully supported.