# regex (Regular Expression) in C++ Error: " terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error' what(): regex_error Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is gcc4.7 buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions)

I compile the code below with "g++ test.cpp -std=gnu++0x" .
Compilation is successful but when I run./a.out it gives error like that I do not understand why it happens. My operating system s Mint.

Error:
"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted (core dumped)
"

```
Code:
// regex_match example
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string s ("this subject has a submarine as a subsequence");
  regex e("sub[a-z]");   // matches words beginning by "sub"
  smatch m;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: gcc doesn't ship with a working regex implementation. You should use Boost.Regex instead.

Comment: Whoever is voting to reopen, this will just get closed again as one of half a dozen duplicates anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn: That's fine, but if there are half a dozen duplicates, it's not too localized, is it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I feel like if interpreting this question narrowly makes it "too localized" and if interpreting it broadly creates a half dozen "exact duplicates," the compromise should not be to leave open.

Comment: The best duplicate is [Is gcc4.7 buggy about regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions), as it gives some more background info.

Comment: @djechlin: I agree.  The correct action is to list the duplicate(s) prominently, which would have happened automatically if the question was closed as a duplicate.  My vote to reopen was in protest to the question being closed as too localized.  I was not aware of the duplicates at the time (because they were not displayed prominently).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code looks fine. GCC's implementation of regex is unusable. Don't waste your time with it.

Comment: See also this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269766/636019