# Understanding std::regex declaration : regex_error exception at runtime

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have the following executable. I compile it with gcc 4.7.2 (g++ foo.cc -std=c++11).

At run time, the exception regex_error is thrown.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
#include <regex>

int main(int, char**){
    std::regex re("\\d");
}
```

**UPDATE** The error code in the exception is error_escape. So I tried "\\d". It doesn't fail at runtime, but I doesn't match againt "1", but it DOES match "\d". So this is clearly not what I want

Comment: AFAIK, g++ does not support regex yet. Your code, compiled with clang, works perfect.

Comment: @soon: libstdc++, not g++

Comment: @soon: "perfectly", not "perfect"

Comment: @Lightness Most useful correction I have *ever* seen on stackoverflow!

Comment: Please put your entire testing program, where we can see that it doesn't match "1" but matches "\d".

Comment: @Fanael, Lightness, thank you for corrections. (Why can't I notice more than one user?)

Comment: Even with today's release of GCC 4.8 and an updated libstdc++, regex is still broken. You're better off using Boost at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer seem to be that the implementation in the GCC4.7 STL is incomplete.
Thank you all for your comments.

[No matches with c++11 regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269766/no-matches-with-c11-regex)

Thank you soon and Nathan Ernst !

Answer (score -3):

Why not catch it?

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**){
    try {
        std::regex re("\\d");
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this explain the exception?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In most cases, `e.what()` will give you a sensible explanation of what's going on...

Comment: The OP already knows which exception is being thrown. The question is _why_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_error suggests that it would give an explanation of what went wrong.

Comment: In this case `e.what()` returns `"regex_error"` which is not very helpful.  If you catch `std::regex_error` explicitly, you can print out the return value of `e.code()` , which you can decipher by looking at the regex header files. However, in this case all of this is a wild goose chase because there is *nothing wrong with the regular expression* -- in this case, gcc 4.7 just has a very broken implementation of regex that fails almost everything.