# How to use <regex> in C++11

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm trying to use a regular expression to accept strings that have sequences like

```
ifelseifelseififif
```

So every else needs an if, but not every if needs an else. I know I could do this with pen and paper with a simple regular expression like this `((if)*+(ifelse)*)*` .Now I'm not sure if I'll be able to do this with the  library as I've never used it before. So would it be possible to accept or reject a string based on a regular expression like the one I wrote above?

I wrote this sample to get my feet wet and I don't understand why it returns false. Isn't regex_search() supposed to find substring matches? That snippet prints nope every time.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string sequence="ifelse";
  regex rx("if");
  if(regex_search(sequence.begin(),sequence.end(),rx)){
    cout<<"match found"<<endl;
  }else{
    cout<<"nope"<<endl;
  }
}
```

I'm using g++ 4.7 and have tried compiling with both `g++ -std=gnu+11 reg.cpp`  and `g++ -std=c++11 reg.cpp`

Comment: not yet fully supported, considering <boost/regex.hpp>. it worked, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060025/is-this-c11-regex-error-me-or-the-compiler).

Comment: possible duplicate of [No matches with c++11 regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269766/no-matches-with-c11-regex)

Comment: @gongzhitaao - "not yet fully supported" doesn't do it justice. There's nothing useful there, and the useless `<regex>` header should not have been put into gcc's library implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling with g++ it may be because regex is not fully supported yet. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) for current C++11 status in g++.

Comment: I added my compiler flag sup above, I guess I'm going to try to switch to visual studio instead of emacs with g++

Comment: @TylerPfaff No need to get drastic. You could just use boost/regex or one of the other available regex implementations out there.

Answer (score 1):

This prints "match found", I just ran it. It wouldn't compile if you weren't using c++11 but heres how I compiled it.
`clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  reg.cpp`

Comment: I added my compiler flag sup above, I guess I'm going to try to switch to visual studio instead of emacs with g++

Comment: generally you will need to use the flag -stdlib=libc++

Comment: @aaronman libc++ is atm pretty much only an option on OSX when using clang.

Comment: How would you make use of c++11 libs on linux or windows than.